# SQL COUNT() WHERE multiple values

Tags: php, sql, count, where-clause

I'll make this post short: I want to count the number of times my row appears in my table where the row is a specific value And another row could be 4 different values. I'll post my "guess" which doesn't work:

```
SELECT hero_selected, COUNT(hero_type) FROM heroes WHERE hero_type = 'agi' AND hero_selected = 'yt' OR hero_selected = 'yb' OR hero_selected = 'ym' OR hero_selected = 'yf
```

### INFORMATION ABOUT THE TABLE

**TABLE NAME**
heroes

**ROW TO COUNT**
hero_type

**SELECT "hero_type" WHERE**
Value is 'agi'

**ONLY SELECT IT WHERE "hero_selected" IS**
Either *yt*, *yb*, *ym* or *yf*

If possible I'd also appreciate the full code including an *echo* of the count amount in php. Thanks A LOT in advance! :)

Comment: Is the missing ' at the end a mis-copy? Also, what results do you get opposed to what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can glean from your question, you want this query

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM heroes
WHERE hero_type = 'agi'
AND hero_selected IN ('yt', 'yb', 'ym', 'yf')
```

PHP code might look like this

```
$db = new PDO(...);
$stmt = $db->query($query);
$count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
echo $count;
```

I'm assuming here that you only want a single count, not one per different `hero_selected` value as the other answers are indicating

Comment: @Xaade Come again? The question asks for *"including an echo of the count amount in php"*

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! Worked perfectly, appreciate the help! By the way, just one question: do you guys get anything from helping people here? By that I mean if you can buy stuff for the reputation points or what it's called. If you don't... then you guys are insanely kind!

Comment: @Cheezen We get that warm, glowing, warming glow. Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM heroes 
WHERE hero_type = 'agi' AND hero_selected IN ('yt', 'yb', 'ym', 'yf')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast answer! But it's not the complete solution to my problem though. I wanted (maybe hard to get from my explanation) only one number.